# Strange margin behaviour of desktop version of my site on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, margin

While browsing the desktop version of my site on a mobile browser (zoomed out to the max) it's showing an extra margin on the right side of the page of aprox. 20px which is not defined so in the css.

As i don't which part of the side is causing this bug im posting the url http://janthoma.ch maybe someone here's knowing an awnser to this little but annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

This i what I found:

```
#main {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Your `#main` to big now (because of the padding) and braks out of #page.

Comment: I admit thats an stupid error but calculating the width with width:calc(100% - 20px); doesn't seem to solve the problem